# Can I buy two of the same mesh system and have them work together?

Tags: mesh-networking

I'm setting up a mesh network, and I'd like 5 nodes.
I'm looking at the Netgear nighthawk mesh wifi 6. Amazon has the 3-node system for $280, and 2 nodes for $200. Netgear sells additional satellite nodes for $120.

I could buy a 3 node, and then two satellites, but that'd cost $280+120+120=$520, but if I bought a 3 and a 2, that would only be $200+280=$480. But would that even work with two routers?

I tried looking up the specs, and 802.11s is supposedly a peer-to-peer system, without a real leader, so it should work, right?

Is there anything from Netgear that says it could work like this?

Comment: What you essentially are asking is if the router, that you are calling a node, can function as a satellite. I think it is unlikely. You should be buying two additional satellites.

Comment: You can create a mesh network from any hardware that supports meshing on WLAN, if you know how to configure it properly. People have done it with RaspPi's, or cheap TP-Link routers with OpenWRT.

Comment: The Amazon eeros all will work as both routers and satellites together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to buy a "2-node" and a "3-node" and combine the satellites together. The "base units" weren't sharable, so I Was able to get 4 nodes with that configuration.

(I contacted netgear first for confirmation)